# Make GeoServer call from the GeoWebCache regardless of screensize

Tags: geowebcache

This is the issue at a very simple level:

We have an instance of GeoServer with GeoWebCache.

The tiles we have cached are all 256x256 which I believe is a standard size.

However, this appears to only work when the map is viewed in a browser on a desktop screen size.

On mobile devices and even on laptops of a smaller screensize. When the map is loaded it is looking for different tile sizes and also it appears to include FORMAT_OPTIONS in the payload with a figure for DPI.

This affects performance of the map under load, is there any easy fix to make the map request the 256x256 tiles regardless of the device screen size?

Comment: this is a client issue not a server problem. I suspect you are looking at the map with a higher resolution screen and the client is trying to request 512x512 tiles to over sample the 256x256 display - you can either set up another grid set or tell it not to do that